# How to add Dropdown in JQUERY DataTable?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, razor

I want to add Drop down with in a Data Table. But it's not working.

Here I am adding the code I tried:

```
_dataTables.markAttendanceTable = $('#markAttendanceTable').DataTable(
{

      dom: '<"pull-right"f>rt<"bottom"ip><"clear">',
      ordering: false,
      searching: false,
      paging: true,
      pageLength: 10,
      fixedColumns: false,        
      data: GetAllMarkAttendance(eventId),
      language: {
          search: "_INPUT_",
          searchPlaceholder: "Search"
      },

      columns: [
        { "data": "Login.Name", "defaultContent": "<i>-</i>" },
        {"data":null ,          

        render: function (d, t, r) {
            debugger;
                var $select = $("<select></select>", {
                    //"id": //r[0]+"start",
                    "id": "Select",
                    "value": "Select"
                });
                $.each(attended, function(k,v){
                    var $option = $("<option></option>", {
                        "text": v,
                        "value": k
                    });
                    if(d === v){
                        $option.attr("selected", "selected")
                    }
                    $select.append($option);
                });
                return $select.prop("outerHTML");
            }
        },


      ],
      columnDefs: [
            { className: "text-left", "targets": [0] },
            { className: "text-center", "targets": [] },

       //{ width: "30%", "targets": [0] },
       //{ width: "25%", "targets": [1] },

      ],
  });
```

Please give me your suggestions.

Comment: In my output i get an drop down but its style is not working. It look like a normal textbox